# Validation loss decreases, then increases, and then decreases again

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

I have the following evolution of cross entropy loss as a function of iteration of a deep CNN classifier I am training. The blue curve is for the training set and the orange curve is for the validation set. I am lost on how can this happen.
 Is there a way to interpret this without going to the specifics of the data and model? What is the interpretation? Where should I say the model started overfitting?

[image]

Comment: The phenomenon is called "double descent" by 

Nakkiran P, Kaplun G, Bansal Y, Yang T, Barak B, Sutskever I. Deep double descent: Where bigger models and more data hurt. Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment. 2021 Dec 29;2021(12):124003.

See also, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482464/how-can-validation-loss-increases-than-slowly-decreases-when-overfitting).

Answer (score 2):

Without more info I would say that your model is overfitting.

Could be many problems, maybe 300... epochs, I guess? are to much for your training data, the learning rate is too high, the data in your training and validation datasets are not well balanced...